# How can I check if my 2d array is full in ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is my hash (2d array). How can I check if its full?

```
$plane = Array.new(27) { |i| Array.new(3) { |i| 0 }}
```

Comment: full as in 'no nils'?

Comment: Well, I'm supposed to fill this hash  with 1, 2 or 3. I want to write a function that at each loop check if there are still 0's.

Comment: When asked for clarification, it's usually best to edit your question, and optionally add a comment saying you've done so.  For example, you could replace the first line with something like "How can I determine if `$plane[i][j]` equals zero for any `i,j`, where:.  Btw, your expression would normally be written `$plane = Array.new(27) { |i| Array.new(3,0) }`.

Comment: To confirm every value is 1, 2 or 3: `$plane.flatten.all? {|n| [1,2,3].include?(n)}`.

Comment: Odds are nearly 100% that you shouldn't be using `$plane` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that your array contains no `0` this would work:

```
if $plane.flatten.none?(&:zero?)
  # no more 0's
end
```

Or the opposite:

```
if $plane.flatten.any?(&:zero?)
  # one or more 0's
end
```

Comment: So how my function would look like? I mean I think if clause should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Use `all?`:

```
$plane.all? { |r| r.all? { |e| e != 0 } }
```

The expression above returns true or false so you can stick the word `if` before it.